# Проблема с переходом на ViewController при помощи presentViewController

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Здравствуйте, у меня не получается сделать красивый переход с одного Вью на другой, только стандартный "горизонтальный флип" (pushViewController), а желаемый - "Cross Dissolve"(presentModalViewController), получается так, что переходит один раз, но второй раз уже перехода не происходит, только у - (pushViewController) работает все нормально.

Переход который работает на всех вьюшках:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *testViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewMenu"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];
```

Переход который работает только один раз, но с желаемым результатом:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *testViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewMenu"];

testViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentViewController:testViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

В чем проблема? Жду вашей помощи!)

****ВОПРОС ЗАКРЫТ, БЫЛА ОШИБКА В КОДЕ****

Comment: //Поднимаю вопрос//

Answer (score 3):

Вы же понимаете разницу между **pushViewController** и **presentViewController**? Что это совершенно разные вещи и **при вызове pushViewController не будет срабатывать анимация, выставленная для modalTransitionStyle**.
Вам следует всегда использовать presentViewController если вы хотите, чтобы этот экран появлялся с такой анимацией.

Общая рекомендация на случай переходов - используйте segue! Перетаскиваем удерживая ctrl с одного вью контроллера на другой (презентуемый) связь, Modal, выставляем ей Transition в Cross Dissolve в инспекторе справа. можно обойтись даже без кода, раз уж вы все равно используете сториборд - это лучший выход

Comment: А вы где-то видите чтоб в коде с pushViewController я указывал анимацию? Не пытайтесь опустить другого программиста, потому что сами выглядите "идиотом".

Вы говорите сейчас мне совсем другую вещь, segue в моем случае отпадает, у меня переход на ВьюК по таймеру..

Comment: Это был просто вопрос понимания разницы, у вас же указан push и modal к одному и тому же UIViewController'y со StoryboardID = "ViewMenu", так? Почему у вас в одном случае это пуш, в другом - это модал? Я попросил разъяснить ситуацию, чтоб было понятнее в чем проблема. А теперь со своим коммнтарием "идиотом" выглядите именно Вы